# Cannot use FileSystemWatcher with coreclr on ubuntu

Tags: .net, ubuntu, asp.net-core, coreclr

I'm trying to use FileSystemWatcher class in coreclr project on Ubuntu but I'm getting following exception:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

my project.json file:

```
{
"version": "1.0.0-*",
"compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
},

"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime": "1.0.1-beta-*",
    "System.IO": "4.0.11-beta-*",
    "System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher": "4.0.0-beta-*",
    "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-*",
    "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-*"
},

"frameworks": {
    "dnxcore50": { }
}
}
```

and Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            using (var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher("."))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Watcher created!");    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

PS. .NET Core installed according to instructions from this site: https://dotnet.github.io/getting-started/

Comment: Try running `dnu restore` in directory, does it succeed?

Comment: @PavelKrymets: that's how I've started - tried dotnet restore, dotnet run. There's no dnu available on my console, but I thought that 'dotnet' it's just an alias to dnu tool. There's no any errors or warnings during restore, everything seems OK.

Comment: Missed that you were using dotnet, i'll check again

Comment: Try removing `-beta` version part in your dependencies to be `"4.0.0-*` etc.

Comment: @PavelKrymets: no difference - the same result after dotnet restore, dotnet run.

Comment: @PavelKrymets: I've installed DNX and it works with dnu run. I thought that 'dotnet' is just an alias to dnx/dnu commands. Where can I read more about the differences?

Comment: I didn't see any public docs on dotnet, but it's quite different concept. I'll file a  bug for your issue thou

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimal version of the **project.json** that works fine with the above **Program.cs** file on my Ubuntu VM:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher": "4.0.0-beta-23516"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-23516"
      }
    }
  }
}
```